# Need a regex or script to not allow previous date

Tags: javascript, date

I want a regex or script which does not allow dates before today.
I tried multiple scripts but none seem to work.

I am expecting once I enter a past date from picker it does not allow.

```js
var currentTime = new Date()
var minDate = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), currentTime.getDate()); //current date
$('#side-datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate: minDate,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
    if (date.getDate() == 1 || date.getDate() == 15) {
      return [true, ''];
    }
    return [false, ''];
  },
});
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add HTML and framework to make a [mcve]

Comment: Also you have 1 and 15 as the only allowed dates

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from selecting dates before today, you can use the minDate option directly in the datepicker initialization.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var minDate = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), currentTime.getDate());

$('#side-datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate: minDate,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    // You can add additional logic here if needed
    return [true, ''];
  },
});
```

In this case, the datepicker won't allow the user to pick dates before the current date. You can change it.

If you're using an input element with the id side-datepicker, make sure it exists in your HTML code.